# Print html to multiple page

Tags: javascript, html, printing

Assuming we have multiple html paragraph

```
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
```

Is there a way to print both to different page to the printer ?

Paragraph 1 would be printed on the first page and Paragraph 2 would be printed on the second page.

Thank You

Comment: stick enough `<br>` tags between them, and they'll end up on different pages. Or, you could just style for print !

Comment: Good way to choke on <br>'s ... :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can do this using CSS [`page-break-after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after) property:

```
@media print {
    p { page-break-after: always; }
}
```

It will print each `p` element on new page.

```js
window.print()
```

```css
@media print {
    @page { margin: 0; }
    p { page-break-after: always; }
}
```

```html
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
```

Comment: Love learning new things; `page-break-after` property. Thanks.

Comment: Note that this does not work in several scenarios for current Chrome.